# SQL Error: table specified more than once

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to execute the following sql instruction in PostgreSQL and when I do that the following error occurs:

> table name "fat_unidades" specified more than once".

Any Help?

```
SELECT  amb_recepcao.sequencial, amb_recepcao.cod_und_atend, atend.nome_fantasia as uni_atendimento
, amb_recepcao.cod_profissional, profissional.nom_pessoa as nom_profissional
, amb_recepcao.cod_atividade, fat_atividades.nom_atividade, amb_recepcao.tipo_pessoa
, amb_recepcao.cod_undpaciente, uni_pacie.nome_fantasia as nom_unidpaciente
, amb_recepcao.cod_paciente, pacie.nom_pessoa as paciente, amb_recepcao.cod_pessoa
, pessoas.nom_pessoa, amb_recepcao.cod_sintoma, amb_sintomas.nom_sintoma
, amb_recepcao.data_atendimento, amb_recepcao.hora_atendimento, amb_recepcao.motivos
, amb_recepcao.acoes_realizadas, amb_recepcao.senha_atendimento
FROM amb_recepcao
LEFT JOIN fat_unidades             ON ( fat_unidades.cod_unidade = amb_recepcao.cod_und_atend )
LEFT JOIN entidades atend          ON ( atend.cod_entidade = fat_unidades.cod_entidade )
LEFT JOIN fat_atividades           ON ( fat_atividades.cod_atividade = amb_recepcao.cod_atividade )
LEFT JOIN entidades uni_pacie      ON ( uni_pacie.cod_entidade = fat_unidades.cod_entidade )
LEFT JOIN pacientes                ON ( pacientes.cod_paciente = amb_recepcao.cod_paciente )
LEFT JOIN fat_unidades             ON ( fat_unidades.cod_unidade = amb_recepcao.cod_undpaciente )
LEFT JOIN pessoas    pacie         ON ( pessoas.cod_pessoa = pacientes.cod_pessoa )
LEFT JOIN pessoas                  ON ( pessoas.cod_pessoa = amb_recepcao.cod_pessoa )
LEFT JOIN amb_sintomas             ON ( amb_sintomas.cod_sintoma = amb_recepcao.cod_sintoma )
LEFT JOIN profissionais            ON ( profissionais.cod_profissional = amb_recepcao.cod_profissional )
LEFT JOIN pessoas     profissional ON ( pessoas.cod_pessoa = profissionais.cod_pessoa )
```

Comment: Well, the message isn't lying.  You specified it twice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have joined to it twice.  If you need to do this, specify an alias for one of your joins,

e.g.

```
LEFT JOIN fat_unidades AS f1 ON f1.cod_unidade ...
```

The duplicate join is marked below

```
**LEFT JOIN fat_unidades** ON ( fat_unidades.cod_unidade = amb_recepcao.cod_und_atend )   
LEFT JOIN entidades atend ON ( atend.cod_entidade = fat_unidades.cod_entidade ) 
LEFT JOIN fat_atividades ON ( fat_atividades.cod_atividade = amb_recepcao.cod_atividade ) 
LEFT JOIN entidades uni_pacie ON ( uni_pacie.cod_entidade = fat_unidades.cod_entidade ) 
LEFT JOIN pacientes ON ( pacientes.cod_paciente = amb_recepcao.cod_paciente ) 
**LEFT JOIN fat_unidades** ON ( fat_unidades.cod_unidade = amb_recepcao.cod_undpaciente ) 
LEFT JOIN pessoas pacie ON ( pessoas.cod_pessoa = pacientes.cod_pessoa )
LEFT JOIN pessoas ON ( pessoas.cod_pessoa = amb_recepcao.cod_pessoa ) 
LEFT JOIN amb_sintomas ON ( amb_sintomas.cod_sintoma = amb_recepcao.cod_sintoma ) 
LEFT JOIN profissionais ON ( profissionais.cod_profissional = amb_recepcao.cod_profissional ) 
LEFT JOIN pessoas profissional ON ( pessoas.cod_pessoa = profissionais.cod_pessoa )
```

Answer (score 3):

Just as the error states, you have the same table `fat_unidades` listed twice among the source tables. The database engine can't tell which table you are referring to when you mention `fat_unidades` in data expressions because both references have the same name. You have to use a table alias with a different name on at least one references to `fat_unidades` so that each reference to that table has a different name.

Answer (score 1):

Use different table alias name